# SSRS removes leading zeros from dates

Tags: reporting-services

so whenever I get a date back from my query I get something like 05/02/2017 HH:MM:SS. However, SSRS will display it as 5/2/2017 HH:MM:SS. I know I can adjust the type of the data cell to display a date value ( with leading zeros) but those options do not display the time.

Any solution to this?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `Format` property of your date field to the below:

`dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss`

This will display your date with leading zeros and also include the time.

Comment: sorry this may sound dumb, but the format in SSRS is not customizable ( from the GUI I see), and my SQL format is already like that.

Comment: It can be customised if you select the date that is not displaying correctly in your report, then go to the properties window. There should then be a `Format` property in the list which you can paste in the format in my answer.

Comment: See [this screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/zKj9cdj.png) for an example of what I mean if you are still struggling.